# How to add a local CA authority on an air-gapped host of Debian

Tags: certificates

Given: an absolutely isolated LAN with a number of web-services using a local CA server.

All user hosts have ca-certificates installed and .crt files were installed by `update-ca-certificates`. Browser-like software, e.g. Chrome and like, are working without reporting.

But every command-line utility, e.g. curl, git, wget, etc. encounter errors because they can't verify local issuer.

Message from curl:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

Most recipes involve just intallation of packages for Internet-wide certs. A few mention use of /etc/pki/whitelist path and `update-ca-trust` script, but both are missing in system or reposutories.

Host OS: Debian 11

Comment: "and .crt files were installed by `update-ca-certificates`": how did you precisely do that? Can you give more details?

Comment: @telcom that's what I did

Comment: @A.B Just after writing that comment I realized that the OP probably did not know that a directory needs to be created under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, as that little pitfall is not exactly obvious and caused me a quite a bit of head-scratching when I first tried to add a local CA certificate "the Debian way". So I wrote my answer, let's see if it helps. I'll be deleting my earlier comments as redundant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a directory under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` with the name of your choosing, and place the public CA certificate of your CA server into it in PEM format, as a `*.crt` file. Then run `update-ca-certificates`.

It will add your local CA certificate in the system-wide `/etc/ssl/certs` in several formats:

- as a OpenSSL-style directory of PEM-formatted certificates with symlinks with certificate hashes at `/etc/ssl/certs`
- as a single file of all trusted CA certs in PEM format at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
- and in any other forms that may be created by any script(s) placed in `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d`, e.g.:

  - if a Java package has been installed, there will be a `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore` script that will generate a JKS keystore of CA certificates as `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`.

There is a man page `man update-ca-certificates`, and more documentation in `/usr/share/doc/ca-certificates`. However, unless you read all the documentation thoroughly, you might miss the fact that **you'll need to create a directory under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`** and place your CA certificate within it; any certificate files at the top `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` level will be ignored.

The `update-ca-certificates` command is used in Debian and related distributions; the `update-ca-trust` you found mentioned originates from Fedora, and seems to be also used in Arch (and related distributions perhaps?).

Both commands do basically the same job, although the exact pathnames vary somewhat between them, as each family of distributions has maintained a slightly different directory hierarchy of system-wide CA certificates.

Comment: Hmm, at which stage they get ignored? update-ca-certuficates certainly does't ignore them, whem messaging "X certificates were added" and they appear in list. But  I was told by LDAP admins not to do sub-dirs and root certificate is in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`

Comment: Oh, it seemed to be required in an older version of Debian. Maybe it was a bug that has been fixed since then.

Comment: The "distributed" location at `/usr/share` probably needs subdirs, the "site" location at `/usr/local/share` didn't as far as I can remember.

Comment: @u1686_grawity /usr/share would also require editing config file. Oddly enough, adding subir kind of worked (still warnings, but no failures now)